# How do you declare an object and make it available throughout your rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying define a connection to an external storage provider. To open the connection, normally I would do

```
storage = Fog::Storage.new {lots more stuff here}
```

This means putting very secret credentials in the code every where I want to access the storage object. **There has to be a better way?**

Answer (score 2):

If you define a constant in a file in `config/initializers`, that file will be `require`d at app start and the constant will be generally available. For instance:

**config/initializers/config.rb**

```
Storage = Fog::Storage.new { stuff }
```

**app/models/mymodel.rb**

```
do_something_with(Storage)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is. Create a `fog.yml` or something, and place it in your `config` folder (you'll want to ignore this in version control).

Then set the credentials:

```
credentials: &credentials
  username: yourname
  password: yourpass

development:
  <<: *credentials

test:
  <<: *credentials

production:
  <<: *credentials
```

(I don't use fog so I don't really know what information you need). Then make a new initializer file, `fog.rb` or something, and place it in `config/initializers`. Put this inside so it gets loaded when the app is initialized:

```
config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/fog.yml")[Rails.env]
FogStorage = Fog::Storage.new { config['username'], config['password'] }
```

Then you can use that global `FogStorage` anywhere.

Again, be sure you ignore the credentials file for version control, and just make a symlink to it in deployment.

Comment: I should point out that Chowlett's answer is basically the same as this, however this just obfuscates the sensitive information a little bit more, which is a GOOD thing for sensitive information, and allows you to remove it from the application completely to ensure safety.